# Push is coming but not updating firebase DB

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, voip, amazon-sns

I have implemented the VOIP push which is sending push notification form amazon SNS. When we are in development mode push is working fine in all three mode(active,background,terminated) and it's updating firebase db(timestamp,lat,long) but when we put it on testflight and check in production then push is coming but not updating firebase db. We have tested this by debugger(breakpoint) in development mode. 
Just to make it sure that push is coming we put local notification inside code mention below

Also push notification is coming when app is terminated but not updating DB in production.

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void){
    var arrTemp = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    arrTemp = payload.dictionaryPayload
    let _ : Dictionary <String, AnyObject> = arrTemp["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    // call back function from getting lat and long from location Manager
    Locator.currentPosition(accuracy: .city, onSuccess: { (loc) -> (Void) in


        isUpdatedUsingSilentPush = true


       if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background ||
        UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive {


        if self.isUserLoggedIn{
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {


                // inside this function we are sending local notification(for testing purpose) as well updating firebase DB
                self.sendLocationToFirebase(manager: Locator, Location: loc)
            })
        }
       }else{
        self.sendLocationToFirebase(manager: Locator, Location: loc)
        }

    }) { (err, loct) -> (Void) in
        print(err)
        print(loct as Any)
      }


    completion()
}
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show how you update the database, so it'll be hard to say why that isn't work. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that gives you the best chances that we can help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the function you are calling must handle firebase with 30 sec or less, follow this "http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/"